# Is Crashplan good for developers?

Tags: visual-studio, crashplan

I am currently examining Crashplan and find it decent except one thing, they have an unavoidable set of excluded files, like part/tmp/temp files and others. While this can be good for media file backup, I worry about backing up projects made with Visual Studio,  Dreamweaver and other IDEs.

The question is, can there be a problem when some project files may be excluded by Crashplan which will prevent the project from a successful compilation upon restore? Maybe this is already a known issue for someone, and I would better know this before buying Crashplan.

Comment: While it can be a solution good a good source control repository is always a better choice.  You can then use Windows Backup + Crashplan continuously keep an bootable image of your system.

Answer (score 1):

Crashplan [offers a trial](http://www.crashplan.com/consumer/crashplan.html).  So try it before you buy it. :)

For some context, here's a CP user's [Tweet](https://twitter.com/SelAromDotNet/statuses/312010387937693696) related to Crashplan and VS:

> thought an old Visual Studio project was deleted forever, thanks to
>   @crashplan it's now safely downloading to my desktop!